# Is there way to generate something according to a grammar?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I want to achieve something which is reverse to parsing. If you have a set of rules, is there way/tool to generate corresponding text? For example, given a set of rules to parse maths expression, the code would automatically output maths expressions.

As I am no expert in this area, in case I post the question in wrong place (apologies in advance), please kindly offer relevant keywords or links so I can continue search.

Comment: Here's one near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036110/how-to-generate-random-programs-from-bnf

Comment: Also, Google found me lots of stuff using the search `generating sentences from grammar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up writing a simple parser for something like below

```
E : p=0.5 E + T | p=0.5 E - T
```

where p stands for probability.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert in this area, and I don't really know of anything that does exactly what you're asking.

However, maybe look into using a recurrent neural network. Karpathy's blog post is excellent and it has some examples of a rnn writing in Shakespeares style or even generating valid XML. 
[Karpathy's blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

Maybe that could help? You can train it on the rules you want to follow and it may come up with some creative writing within those rules.